# Recommended version of PHP?

Tags: php

What PHP version would you recommend for running CiviCRM version 4.6.8?

I was using an old version of PHP (4.3.3), but that is no longer sufficient to run CiviCRM and 5.4+ is recommended in the documentation. Would it be wise to upgrade to the latest version 5.6.13 or might I be safer with something like 5.5.29?

Comment: Note that the answer to this Oct 2015 question changes over time; see also http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/what-is-the-recommended-level-of-php-for-civicrm-there-seems-to-be-some-inconsi which is from Feb 2016.

Comment: See the Installation Guide for the latest recommendations https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/stable/general/requirements/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safest bet is probably 5.5. 5.6 ought to work but hasn't been tested as thoroughly. As a core CiviCRM developer I currently use 5.5.9 in my test environment.

You should also look at which version is recommended for your CMS, often that is more of a limiting factor.