# What is the recommended level of PHP for CiviCRM? There seems to be some inconsistencies

Tags: 4.7, php, 4.6.10, coding-standards

See the [wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installation+and+Upgrades) which says the minimum level is 5.4+

But see this [linked page from the wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements) which recommends 5.6 with a bare minimum of 5.3.10.

See also the system status for release 4.7 which says the minimum recommendation is 5.5

Which is it?

Comment: I introduced one of those inconsistencies when I edited [CiviCRM PHP Requirements](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+PHP+Requirements) recently in reply to [a question from a user on unsupported PHP7](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/error-during-drupal-installation-mysql-support-not-included-in-php/9325). I recommend using a supported version of PHP; [here's the list of supported versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). Hopefully a core team member can give a canonical answer.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that - I've reverted the wiki to be consistent, then rephrased it to seem less like it's recommending PHP5.4 (which I don't think is the intent) and added a note to consider security updates also.

Answer (score 6):

[CiviCRM PHP requirements](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php) *recommends* PHP5.5 **or greater**, and notes PHP5.3.10 is the bare minimum *required*. As well as this, you want to be sure your PHP version is actively getting [security updates](http://php.net/supported-versions.php), and also consider [what PHP versions CiviCRM is tested with](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9607/what-versions-of-php-are-used-in-civicrms-internal-qa).

As of Feb 2016, **I recommend PHP5.6** -

- Support ended for PHP5.3 in 2014, and for 5.4 in 2015.
- PHP 5.5 is getting only security fixes until mid 2016.
- PHP 5.6 is actively supported until Dec 2017, with security fixes until Dec 2019.
- CiviCRM doesn't run on PHP7 *yet ...* ([CRM-17789: Support PHP7](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17789)).

NB: Distributions may backport security fixes for older versions after those dates; please do your own diligence on whether your PHP version is secure :)

Comment: Make sure that you say PHP 5.3.10 as a bare minimum.  CentOS 6.7 has PHP 5.3.3, which it would not allow when I upgraded from 4.6.11 to 4.7.0.  Hence the mess I'm trying to sort out now.

Comment: Done, thanks. If CentOS / RHEL still ship 5.3.x, I hope they are backporting security fixes for it!

Comment: Backporting is what has made RHEL the standard for server installs and why CentOS/Scientific exist.  In fact, from what I understand of their backporting process, even a number of the newer PHP functions get backported to their 5.3.3 branch.  (As with many of their other packages.)

Comment: As of the 4.7 release we recommend 5.5+ with the bare minimum requirement still at 5.3.10. I've updated your answer and the wiki page to match.

Comment: If you've got Centos6 or RHEL6, then I recommend you use https://ius.io/ to update php to 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

Chris' answer is correct.  However, a coworker reported at least one instance of an extension that did not run correctly on PHP 5.3 (I'm afraid I don't know which), so this answer applies to core CiviCRM only.

Comment: Sparkpost will not run at 5.3

Comment: [Mailchimp also requires > 5.3 now](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/285).