# What versions of PHP are used in CiviCRM's internal QA?

Tags: php, testing, coding-standards

The wiki currently states that CiviCRM has bare minimum (5.3.10) and recommended (>= 5.4) PHP requirements.

Knowing what CiviCRM has been tested with can help identify what should be expected to work reliably.

- As of today, what versions of PHP do CiviCRM's test infrastructure test with?
- This question will become out of date over time; for future reference, is there a better place to check this information?
- For orgs who aren't able to match the PHP versions that CiviCRM is tested with internally, what other options are available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- At time of writing, all PRs tests and scheduled tests run under Ubuntu 12.04 (PHP 5.3.10). There is an effort underway to introduce a test node for Ubuntu 16.04 (PHP 7.0) (although details are still a bit in flux).
- When you inspect the results of a test run, you can get some details (such as the node name and console output). The node names follow a convention -- `test-ubu1204-5` is running Ubuntu 12.04 (precise); `test-ubu1604-1` is running Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial).

  - This tells you the general platform and hints at the PHP version. I'd like to keep these generally aligned with upstream versions.
  - As a somewhat stronger statement, I want to keep the test nodes aligned with [`civi-download-tools --full`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/bin/civi-download-tools), which autoinstalls system requirements on some common builds of Ubuntu/Debian. If you know the target platform, you can lookup a more specific list of packages.