# CiviCRM 4.7 WP and CentOS 6 PHP repo

Tags: wordpress, php, webserver

I am in complete disagreement with Coleman that this is off-topic and should be shoved out to the General Unix and Linux StackExchange.  As I seem to be unable to communicate with Coleman through StackExchange, I am reposting this question.

CentOS has their listed repo's at:  https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories  I'd prefer not to get unnecessarily toasted over generally available information.

As one can see, there are many different ones.  However, what are the dev's using?  What's being tested against?  CentOS 6 is still a supported product, yet CiviCRM 4.7 pushes the PHP recommendations past what is default PHP install is for any CentOS/RHEL/Scientific packaging.  CentOS 7.2, the newest general release is paired with the PHP 5.4 branch, yet the recommended PHP for CiviCRM is the 5.6 branch.

This is CiviCRM specific.  What are the dev's expecting when I install CiviCRM?  I can choose a million different ways to install PHP, but only a few of them may work as expected.

Is there any kind of "official" repo for upgrading PHP beyond the stock PHP 5.3.3 found in CentOS 6.7? I'm trying to utilize the SCL repo's, but finding all sorts of peculiarities that seem to point back to this dual PHP install method.

Comment: To be fair, your original question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261542/civicrm-4-7-wp-and-centos-6-php-repo only mentioned CiviCRM in the title. I read the original and did not understand readily how it was connected to CiviCRM.  You have explained in this iteration much more clearly how this is relevant to Civi and the Civi community.

Comment: Not a direct answer -- but related: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/what-is-the-recommended-level-of-php-for-civicrm-there-seems-to-be-some-inconsi

Comment: In retrospect, I can see how one might lean that way.  To be honest, I didn't feel it was necessary to go to such lengths, having CiviCRM in the title in a CiviCRM forum seemed redundant as it was.  I tried to give the relevant information without overstating.  I guess my head's too far into this problem and it needed more history for others.

Comment: I did wonder if this question was a better fit for unix.stackexchange.com but saw that a few other "how to get modern php?" questions there went unanswered. There seem to be lots of people hitting PHP version issues with the 4.7 upgrade so I'm happy for this Q to stay.