# What is the minimum PHP version for CiviVolunteer?

Tags: php, civivolunteer

Some screens for CiviVolunteer on PHP 5.3.x - e.g. 
/civicrm/volunteer/loghours?reset=1&action=add&vid=2&snippet=json
produce a 500 Error (pop up text: 'Network' error; please refresh and try again).

[13-Apr-2016 08:43:08] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in .../org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php on line 68

On PHP 5.6.x all is well. So we'll upgrade this site - just posting this question here for others running into 'Network' errors.

Comment: Hi, Karin. Which version of volunteer is this? This is the first I've heard of this problem... Most of the 'Network' errors I've seen are due to... well, actual network problems... or insufficient user permissions. FWIW, my development environment is PHP 5.6, though I'm not intentionally excluding other versions...

Comment: Hi Frank - this is CiviVolunteer 4.6-2.0.1 - Googling the Fatal Error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active made me try an exact clone of that entire site/project on a >PHP 5.3 version - [I use PHP 5.6 on my dev as well] and all is working as expected. The CiviCRM project as a whole should probably sharpen up the minimum requirements on PHP version - as many of us are writing extensions on > PHP 5.3. PS - I didn't see this was a 500 Error until I checked the console in Firebug - and that prompted me to check the php-fpm log.

Comment: See also http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9473/what-is-the-recommended-level-of-php-for-civicrm-there-seems-to-be-some-inconsi/9579#9579